# Building Sencha App for iOS error

Tags: ios, build, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

since I dont get an answer on sencha touch forum I will ask you fellows how to build my sencha app for iOS.

Actually, since I upgraded to the SDK Tools RC, I am able to package and run it for iOSSimulator.

But when I try to package to iOS it gives me the following error:

on terminal:

```
sencha package myconfig.json
```

Error:

> The application was successfully packaged
>
> codesign_allocate: for architecture armv7 object: /Users/kinhow/Documents/myapp/build///My App.app/stbuild_template malformed object (unknown load command 8)
>
> /Users/kinhow/Documents/myapp/build///My App.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
>
> Failed to execute system command while signing application with error 256
>
> Failed to package application

Hope you guys can save me

Answer (score 1):

The packager uses Mac OS X built-in utility codesign. Load command 8 is VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS and if codesign does not understand it that means on your computer it's outdated, you can either update your OS or install latest Xcode.